# Creating a store for each country with multiple language

Tags: magento-1.9, language

I am starting a Magento project for 7 countries, I want to add for each country two languages English and Arabic.

All stores have the same products. As first thought I think the best approach to have a store for each country, and each store has two store views.

The problem that each country should have different url.

For example

```
www.mystore.com/country1
www.mystore.com/country2
www.mystore.com/country3
```

And the user should be able to change the language without changing showing the language code in the url.

I found a website that is using that approach http://markavip.com/

So could you please suggest a way to do it ??

**Edit one:** What I did step by step

**First Step :** I created a new website with code 'qatar', then I created a new store with Default Category as Root Category ( because I want the same products for all stores ). Then I created a view for the store.

**Second Step :** After that I created a new sub folder called qatar and I copied the .htaccess file and add this code.

```
SetEnvIf Host / MAGE_RUN_CODE=qatar;
SetEnvIf Host / MAGE_RUN_TYPE=website;
```

No reason for it because I couldn't find the explanation with sub folder.

**Third step:** I changed **Auto-redirect to Base URL** in default config to **No**, and then I changed the **Base Link URL** in qatar website to **{{secure_base_url}}qatar/**

I tested it using this url magento:8888/qatar/ in my machine and it shows this :

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /qatar/ on this server.
```

To solve the problem I copied the index.php and add this code

```
$mageRunCode='qatar';
$mageRunType='website';
```

Then I test it again it work but when I go this category page it shows

> There are no products matching the selection.

So when I access the main website

magento:8888/men/shirts.html

I can see all products. but at this url I can't see any product

magento:8888/qatar/men/shirts.html

**Edit Two:** I update the product to be in the second website also. And it work perfectly, but could you please see my steps because I am afraid that I may did a hidden mistake.

Comment: @Marius Could you please see the update post. I don't thinks it is a duplicate because I want to create different stores for the same domain but different url.

Comment: You did right. Please add a answer and mark it as solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is:

- Different websites for each country
- different store views for each language
- don't show store view code in url

Comment: I did it and search a lot but now I have a problem with products in the second website could you see the updated post.